# Showpost and last wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need your help.

I would like to bring up the last (number) from my template classified ads. Here's the code:

```
    <?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'showposts' => 10,
            'post_type' => 'ad',
            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'ad_category',
                                'field' => 'id',
                                'terms' => array('8')
                                )
                            )
    ));
if($the_query->have_posts()):
?>
<div class="feat-ad column col12"><!-- featured ad -->
     <h3 class="widget-title">Category</h3>
    <ul id="first-carousel" class="first-and-second-carousel">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <?php colabs_image('width=150&height=150&play=true');?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>   
    </ul>
</div><!-- end featured ad -->
<?php endif;?>
```

I tried with showpost, but nothing appears in one ad ... this is not even the last announcement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the posts_per_page parameter instead of showposts

> posts_per_page (int) - number of post to show per page (available with Version 2.1, replaced showposts parameter). Use 'posts_per_page'=>-1 to show all posts (the 'offset' parameter is ignored with a -1 value). Set the 'paged' parameter if pagination is off after using this parameter. Note: if the query is in a feed, wordpress overwrites this parameter with the stored 'posts_per_rss' option. To reimpose the limit, try using the 'post_limits' filter, or filter 'pre_option_posts_per_rss' and return -1

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters